# Efficient reverse of queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset, models

I'm trying to look at the most efficient way to traverse my models to get the data that I'm after.  I have three "related" models. `Item`, `ProtectionList` and `Player`

**Protection List**

```
class ProtectionList(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    main_hand = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='main_hand')
    off_hand = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='off_hand')
    head = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='head')
    neck = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='neck')
    shoulder = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='shoulder')
    back = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='back')
    chest = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='chest')
    wrist = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='wrist')
    hands = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='hands')
    waist = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='waist')
    legs = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='legs')
    feet = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='feet')
    ring1 = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='ring1')
    ring2 = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='ring2')
    trinket1 = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='trinket1')
    trinket2 = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True, related_name='trinket2')
    locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.player.main_character.name
```

**Player**

```
class Player(models.Model):
    accountID = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    battletag = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    main_character = models.ForeignKey('Character', null=True, blank=True, related_name='main_character')
    signature = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
         return self.battletag
```

**Item**

```
class Item(models.Model):
    '''Details individual data for each item on a loot table'''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    item_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    dropped_by = models.ForeignKey(Boss)
    warforgeable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    bonus_string = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I need to map my way back to the `Player` to make a list of `Player` objects dependant on who has the `Item` in any field on their `ProtectedList`.

I know `Item` is related to `ProtectionList` and `ProtectionList` to `Player` however I want to find an efficient way of checking in all the fields where `Item` is a ForeignKey within the `ProtectionList` object as the `Item` being filtered could potentially be in any field (minus the `player` and `locked` fields).

I have considered the use of Q to OR each of the fields, but I'm not sure how optimal this would be on larger querysets.

I am also looking at through intermediate tables and changing the model to a many-to-many.

Comment: I think you are having a hard time because your model is wrong. Rather than all these foreign keys, link to item once using a ManytoMany with an intermediate table (Django calls this a "through" model) containing the name you're currently using as a field name. If you do it this way your query becomes very easy.

Comment: How would I then reference which slot the item is in if it's not explicitly defined?

Comment: The intermediate table ("through" model) allows you to store extra data, which could be a string field like `slot_name` set to a value, e.g., "off_hand" or "main_hand". Now you just filter the m2m relations (by querying the "through" model usually) that match the item and character in question, and determining the slot is as simple as examining the CharField on the object you ended up selecting this way.

Comment: @NeilAshleyHickman You could add an extra field in the intermediate table for the slot.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist ok, any chance you could show an example? I've always had trouble with using through in the past. Going to read up on it again.

Comment: I am short on time atm, hence the comments. If I check later (I always look back at my activity when I get on) and there is still nothing/you haven't figured it out, I will try to write an SSCCE for this. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may be wrong, but i feel like your model structure is not normalized. You have a M2M relation between `Player` and `Item` via `Slots`. Consider the following model structure:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Slot(models.Model):
    #e.g. main_hand, off_hand, head, ... , feet
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class Item(models.Model):
    '''Details individual data for each item on a loot table'''
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
    item_id = models.IntegerField(null=True)
    """removed for the example"""
    #dropped_by = models.ForeignKey(Boss)
    warforgeable = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    bonus_string = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=False, default='')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name


class PlayerManager(models.Manager):
    def create_player_with_empty_slots(self, **kwargs):
        player = Player.objects.create(**kwargs)
        PlayerSlot.objects.bulk_create([
            PlayerSlot(player=player, slot=slot) for slot in Slot.objects.all()
        ])
        return player


class Player(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    """removed for the example"""
    #accountID = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    #battletag = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True, blank=True)
    #main_character = models.ForeignKey('Character', null=True, blank=True, related_name='main_character')
    #signature = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)

    slots = models.ManyToManyField(Slot, through='PlayerSlot')
    items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, through='PlayerSlot')

    objects = PlayerManager()

    def __unicode__(self):
        """changed for the example"""
        return self.user.username

    def get_slot(self, slot_or_slotname):
        if isinstance(slot_or_slotname, Slot):
            return self.playerslot_set.get(slot=slot_or_slotname)
        else:
            return self.playerslot_set.get(slot__name=slot_or_slotname)

    def set_item(self, item, at_slot):
        slot = self.get_slot(at_slot)
        slot.item = item
        slot.save()


class PlayerSlot(models.Model):
    player = models.ForeignKey(Player)
    slot = models.ForeignKey(Slot)
    #item is optional, to allow empty slots
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, null=True, blank=True)
    locked = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('player', 'slot')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "{player} carry {item} on {slot}".format(player=self.player, item=self.item or 'nothing', slot=self.slot)
```

#### Playing with the API's

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> from game.models import Slot, Item, Player, PlayerSlot
```

Lets create some initial data:

```
>>> Slot.objects.bulk_create([
...     Slot(name='main_hand'),
...     Slot(name='off_hand'),
...     Slot(name='head'),
...     Slot(name='neck'),
...     Slot(name='shoulder'),
...     Slot(name='back'),
...     Slot(name='chest'),
...     Slot(name='wrist'),
...     Slot(name='hands'),
...     Slot(name='waist'),
...     Slot(name='legs'),
...     Slot(name='feet'),
...     Slot(name='ring1'),
...     Slot(name='ring2'),
...     Slot(name='trinket1'),
...     Slot(name='trinket2'),
... ])
[<Slot: main_hand>, <Slot: off_hand>, <Slot: head>, <Slot: neck>, <Slot: shoulder>, <Slot: back>, <Slot: chest>, <Slot: wrist>, <Slot: hands>, <Slot: waist>, <Slot: legs>, <Slot: feet>, <Slot: ring1>, <Slot: ring2>, <Slot: trinket1>, <Slot: trinket2>]


>>> Item.objects.bulk_create([
...     Item(name='Short Sword'),
...     Item(name='Sabre'),
...     Item(name='Broadsword'),
...     Item(name='Apprentice Broadsword'),
...     Item(name='Monster Hunter'),
... ])
[<Item: Short Sword>, <Item: Sabre>, <Item: Broadsword>, <Item: Apprentice Broadsword>, <Item: Monster Hunter>]


>>> user1 = User.objects.create_user('john', 'lennon@thebeatles.com', 'johnpassword')
>>> user2 = User.objects.create_user('paul', 'mccartney@thebeatles.com', 'mccartnypassword')

>>> player1 = Player.objects.create_player_with_empty_slots(user=user1)
>>> player2 = Player.objects.create_player_with_empty_slots(user=user2)
```

Get all player slots:

```
>>> player1.slots.all()
[<Slot: main_hand>, <Slot: off_hand>, <Slot: head>, <Slot: neck>, <Slot: shoulder>, <Slot: back>, <Slot: chest>, <Slot: wrist>, <Slot: hands>, <Slot: waist>, <Slot: legs>, <Slot: feet>, <Slot: ring1>, <Slot: ring2>, <Slot: trinket1>, <Slot: trinket2>]
```

Get all player items:

```
>>> player1.items.all()
[]
```

Adding new item?

```
>>> broadsword = Item.objects.get(name='Broadsword')
>>> player1.set_item(broadsword, at_slot='main_hand')
>>> player1.items.all()
[<Item: Broadsword>]
```

Check what is inside some slot?

```
>>> player1.get_slot('main_hand')
<PlayerSlot: john carry Broadsword on main_hand>
```

Find players having a item:

```
>>> Player.objects.filter(items=broadsword)
[<Player: john>]
```

Some more example's by Two-Bit Alchemist:

Here are some example queries for this model structure:

1. You have a Player object `player` and need to know what is in his/her left hand:

   ```
   player.items.filter(slot__name='off_hand')[0].item    # Could be None
   ```
2. You have an Item object `item` and wish to know what slot `player` has it equipped in:

   ```
   PlayerSlot.objects.filter(player=player).filter(item=item)[0].slot.name
   ```
3. You have an Item object `item` and wish to know what players have this item at all:

   ```
   PlayerSlot.objects.filter(item=item).all()
   ```

or

```
    Player.objects.filter(slots__item=item).all()
```

depending on which object you'd rather work with. I haven't tested any of the queries above but this should get you started. Also note that chaining this way (queries 1 & 2) may throw `IndexError` if the relationships don't line up the way you think (e.g., `player` does not actually have `item`), so be prepared to possibly catch that.

#### Migrating old data

I believe something like this can do the job:

```
plist_slots = [
    'main_hand', 'off_hand', 'head', 'neck', 'shoulder', 
    'back', 'chest', 'wrist', 'hands', 'waist', 'legs',
    'feet', 'ring1', 'ring2', 'trinket1', 'trinket2'
]

Slot.objects.bulk_create([
    Slot(name=slot) for slot in plist_slots
])

plist = ProtectionList.objects.all().select_related(
    *list(['player'] + plist_slots)
)

for p in plist:
    PlayerSlot.objects.bulk_create([
        PlayerSlot(
            player=p.player,
            item=getattr(p, slot),
            slot=Slot.objects.get(name=slot)
        ) for slot in plist_slots
    ])
```

Comment: +1 for `unique_together`. Perhaps you could add an example of how to use these relationships, e.g. finding all the players with a certain item, as I believe that's what the OP is asking.

Comment: I'll try to do this tomorrow, need some sleep now :-)

Comment: btw looking at unique together again its better to unique only player and slot, cuz I guess it wont be OK to have two items at a same slot. Gonna edit it now.

Comment: The only concern I have here is the data migration.

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I meant. @NeilAshleyHickman Do you not use [South](http://south.aeracode.org/)?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I use django 1.7 so I'm using migrations. But I'm slightly concerned that I will lose a lot of data by changing the models to this. I know that it's the optimal way of doing it and I really want to Change to this method but I really can't lose the data I already have.

Comment: @NeilAshleyHickman You should never lose data during a migration. You simply change your models partly or all the way to this before you delete ProtectionList, then write a script or data migration that transfers over the data, and finally make a new schemamigration that deletes ProtectionList.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist reassuring :) I'll give it a go now. Thanks for all your help I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: Added example queries to the end of the answer. As noted, untested and may throw certain exceptions if certain criteria are not met.

Comment: OK, guys, sorry for being late. I added some more examples and give you a tip how can u migrate the data.

Comment: @Todor your last example for the migration, the p in plist for loop i'm getting an integrity error IntegrityError: UNIQUE constraint failed: players_playerslot.player_id, players_playerslot.slot_id

Comment: The migration code is not tested its purpose is to give a direction about how the problem can be solved. The error you get itself says that for some reason the code is trying to insert two rows for the same player-slot pair. Do you have duplicate `ProtectionList` in your database? E.g. two `protectionLists` pointing at the same `Player`. If you inspect and debug that, the problem would be solved.

Comment: no just the one protection list, i'll have a feel around see what I can debug.

Comment: I wish I could upvote this answer more than once.  Best answer I've ever received. Works a treat and I now understand how through M2M relationships work. Thanks guys.

Comment: :) You are welcome. If you haven't done it already you can read more about the `through` model here => [extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships). Actually the whole page is a must-read.

Comment: just out of interest, how could I use `player1.get_slot('main_hand')` in the template?

Comment: I'm trying to iterate over each slot in the template and get each item. I know what the player is in the template, how can I get to the slot name and item from there? Player.items.all() works, but there's not seeming to be a relationship between the item and the slot in that queryset.

Comment: You need to use the `PlayerSlot` model. It is available via `player.playerslot_set` for each `player` (checkout how the `get_slot` method use it). To optimize the query performance for some set of `players` you can use `prefetch_related` and `select_related`. E.g. `Player.objects.all()[:10].prefetch_related(Prefetch('playerslot_set', queryset=PlayerSlot.objects.all().select_related('slot', 'item')))`. Now iterating over this `queryset` and each `player.playerslot_set` will be a very cheap operation - two queries only.